# Две разные навигации на сайте Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

есть такая задача: реализовать две навигации на сайте(одну в хедере, а другую в футере).
код в functions.php:

```
function addMenuHeaderClass( $ulclass ) {
    return preg_replace( '/<a /', '<li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__list-link"', $ulclass );
}

function addMenuFooterClass( $ulclass ) {
    return preg_replace( '/<a /', '<li class="footer__menu-item"><a class="footer__menu-link"', $ulclass );
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'addMenuHeaderClass' );
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'addMenuFooterClass' );
```

код в хедере:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'menu'           => 'header-menu',
  'container'      => '',
  theme_location' => 'header-menu',
  'items_wrap'     => '<ul class="menu__list">%3$s</ul>',
) );
?>
```

код в футере:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'menu'           => 'footer-menu',
  'container'      => '',
  'theme_location' => 'footer-menu',
  'items_wrap'     => '<ul class="footer__menu-list">%3$s</ul>',
) );
?>
```

Но проблема в том, что к меню в хедере применяются стили из меню в футере.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Непонятно нафига этот код с реглярками. Просто создать меню и вывести его. А "не применяются стили" - см наследование. И да в коде хедера ошибка синтаксиса. Но может это ты неправильно сюда вставил.

Comment: Прописывай стили классам футера и хедера, и они не будут переопределяться